# How to replace escape characters in Regular expression?

Tags: c#, regex, escaping, character

Once again I have hit the wall.

How to replace escape characters using regular expressions?
If tab character (\t) occures more than twice, I want to replace those two or more occurances by single \t.
For example if \t\t\t comes, then I want to replace it with \t only.
How  to do this?

I am facing one more problem regarding reading text file and applying regular expressions to it.

I am using C# to read text file and for regular expressions.
When I open text file (file having txt extension), I get a normal view of file. But when I read the same file using "textReader" and store it into string, I get text something like this :

> O K\t\t\t\t\t\tEmail:
>   k.o@gmail.com \rPhone:   + 91
>   992\t\r\rExperience Summary
>   \rBusiness Intelligence and data
>   warehouse designer with more than 6
>   years of work experience in OLAP
>   Project.\r\r\rTechnology\rBelow is a
>   list of important software products
>   and tools that I have worked
>   with.\r\rSoftware
>   Products\r\a\r\aOperating
>   Systems:\rWINDOWS NT, WINDOWS 2000,
>   UNIX\rDatabase Management
>   Systems:\rOracle 8i, Oracle 9i, Oracle
>   10g, SQL-Server 7.0,  DB2\rSoftware
>   Packages:\rVSS, ER Win, M1\rFourth
>   Generation Language:\rPL/SQL,
>   SQL*PLUS\rTools &
>   Technologies:\rOracle Warehouse
>   Builder 10.1.0.4.0, ORACLE 9i AS,
>   ORACLE Discoverer Reports Data Stage
>   8.0, Fast Track 8.5, DB@ Cube, JavaScript, JSP, JDEV, BI BEANS, ASP,
>   ASP.NET, Ab
>   Initio\r\r\a\r\a\v\r\r\fAssignments\rThe
>   details of the various assignments
>   that I have handled are listed here,
>   in chronological
>   order.\r\rName\r\aAvery Dennison Data
>   Warehousing\r\a\r\aClient\r\aAvery
>   Dennison, he challenge in the project
>   is to feed EDW from existing
>   warehouses which has data at an
>   aggregated
>   level.\r\a\r\a\r\rName\r\aAOL BI
>   (Omniture)\rite team. Designing,
>   coding and testing along with
>   coordination with Onsite team.
>   \r\a\r\aTools & Technologies\r\aUnix
>   Platform, Oracle 10g , Py. Not only
>   delivering the correct requirement but
>   also the performance has to be in
>   acceptable
>   range.\r\a\r\a\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\rName\r\aAIW
>   Events (ABSA)\r\a\r\aClient\r\aABSA,
>   South Africa\r\a\r\aP

i.e, all the escape characters like \s, \r, \f are visible. Because of this, the regular expression that works with normal text doesnt work when I read same text into string variable.

Anyone one knows how to solve  this problem?

Thanks

I have one more query. I want to match text at the end of the line. I tried to use $ for this. For example, to match text ending with "assignment", I used regex assignment$.It worked with normal text. But when I run this regx on text given by streamreader, this regex doesnt work. Stream reader gives strings like Assignments\r\r\f.How to match end of line or start of line with this kind of text?

Comment: Aren't you violating the privacy of Karim by showing to everyone those details? Is this public accessible or test/fake information?

Comment: offtopic: I guess Osama Karim will be pleased to see this information published here ;-)

Comment: I guess he will be pleased ;) But this does not explain and justify this, unless this is public information or he has given explicit permission to do so :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to match the string `"\r"`, right? You'll have to escape the escape character to do it:

```
"(\\r)*"
```

This expression will match `"\r"` any number of times. It works because `"\\"` escapes to a literal `"\"`. You can apply the same idea to match `"\t"`, too.

Comment: Thanks.
I have one more query.
I want to match text at the end of the line.
I tried to use $ for this. For example, to match text ending with "assignment", I used regex assignment$.It worked with normal text. But when I run this regx on text given by streamreader, this regex doesnt work. Stream reader gives strings like Assignments\r\r\f.How to match end of line or start of line with this kind of text?

Comment: @shekhar: You can add a check for `\r\r\f$` instead of just `$`, like this: `"assignments\\r\\r\\f$"`

Answer (score 2):

```
/\t{2,}/\t/
```

replaces two or more tabs with a single character.

Answer (score 1):

You could replace `\\t\\t\\t` with `\\t{3}`

Comment: you could this with just \t{3}

Comment: @Manu, you are correct, I've modified my post. Thanks for the remark.

Answer (score 1):

For the tab char use something like this:

```
/(\t)*/\1/g
```

1. Make a group with one char (the tab char) and match it as much as possible.
2. Replace the full match with the single character
3. (Global) use the pattern for the full text.

Then you could use the same expression for the other escaped chars you want to replace.